# Language design: default method parameters inheritance

Tags: c++

I think, there is a common situation, when one function (a) is being called from within another one (b), while 'a' have some default parameters and 'b' is needed to support them. For example:

```
void a(int v1, int v2=0, int v3=1);
void b(int m1, int m2, int v1, int v2=0, int v3=1) {
    // ...
    a(v1, v2, v3);
    // ...
}
```

But this is the violation of the DRY principle. It can leads a subtile bug, when default parameter of 'a' was changed, but not changed in 'b':

```
void a(int v1, int v2, int v3=0);
void b(int m1, int m2, int v1, int v2=0, int v3=1) {
    // ...
    a(v1, v2, v3);
    // ...
}
```

Why there is no mechanism in C++ to inherit default parameter values? It might look like:

```
void a(int v1, int v2=0, int v3=1);
void b(int m1, int m2, int v1, int v2=default(a::v2, 0), int v3=default(a::v3, 1)) {
    // ...
    a(v1, v2, v3);
    // ...
}
```

Whether there are languages, that have such syntax?

*It might be an offtopic on this board?*

Comment: This wouldn't really be on-topic here, no. We tend more toward practical "this code isn't working" sorts of questions. Your question *might* be OK on Programmers.SE, but I can't be sure. The *topic* is definitely a better fit for them.

Comment: I removed the C tag because C does not have default parameters.

Comment: Well in C++ you could solve this issue by overloading `b` (with 3, 4 and 5 parameters). If you don't want to write the overloads yourself, you could use a variadic template / parameter pack. Alternatively, you could use something like a `boost::optional` as parameter (for `b`) *with a default argument*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is actually the use of magic numbers. If you remove the magic numbers, the problem is resolved nicely.

```
enum DefaultA { DefaultA_v2 = 0, DefaultA_v3 = 1 };

void a(int v1, int v2=DefaultA_v2, int v3=DefaultA_v3);

void b(int m1, int m2, int v1, int v2=DefaultA_v2, int v3=DefaultA_v3) {
    // ...
    a(v1, v2, v3);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And once again, another level of indirection solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"But this is the violation of the DRY principle. It can leads a subtile bug, when default parameter of 'a' was changed, but not changed in 'b'"

Frankly, I'd say that if you get this "bug", then your functions are too tightly-coupled. Standalone functions are supposed to, well, stand alone. If changing a default parameter for one function causes another function to break, I think you have a design problem there.